# xlsxwriter showing error after created dist/.exe file with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze, xlsxwriter

I have created a program that works fine. It grabs data from a SQL database, manipulates it a bit, and creates reports in excel using xlsxwriter. I am trying to create a .exe file so I can send it to some colleagues who aren't programmers. Like I said, it works fine even after I do the setup.py build piece of converting it to an .exe. The problem I get is once I do the setup.py dist_msi part, it begins to give me an error. The GUI works fine and the calculations as well, it is converting it to excel that is messing up.

I am getting the following error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Renewals.xlsx'

Renewals.xlsx is the file name it is trying to create. I understand that xlsxwriter programs need to explicitly close the file with workbook.close(), and my code does this. The code is below:

```
def run_renewals(as_of_date, groups):

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Renewals.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    workbook = writer.book

    for x in groups:

        A bunch of code

    workbook.close()
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?  Thanks

Comment: I assume this is on Windows? If so, if the file is open you will get this error in addition to a real permissions issue. Perhaps try creating a file that you know does not exist?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Yes, I am using windows. I tried renaming the file to one that does not exist and I am getting the same error. I got everything working with py2exe but I'd rather use cx_Freeze.

Comment: Can you provide a sample that demonstrates the problem? I've used xlsxwriter quite well within cx_Freeze. Which version are you using?

Comment: setup(
        name = "PA Renewal App",
        options = {"PA Renewal App": {"packages":        ["PyQt","pandas","numpy","xlsxwriter"], "include_files":["PALIG.jpg"]}},
        version = "0.1",
        description = "PA Renewal App",
        executables =         [Executable("PA_Database_Manager.py")]
    )

Comment: Above is my setup.py. My versions are 0.85 for xlsxwriter and 4.3.4 for cx_Freeze. I think you are looking for different code than my setup.py but I'm a little confused. The code in my original question is basically a summary what my script looks like.